# Where to place authorisation within an MVC web application?

Tags: model-view-controller, web-applications, architecture, authorization

## Scenario

You are building a web application for your marketing department. The marketing
department have requested a blogging platform so they can keep your customers
up to date with the latest company news. You decide to build a traditional MVC
web application with a relational database. You choose a LAMP (Linux Apache PHP
MySQL) stack or similar.

The requirements of the marketing team are very simple. They want:

- Any member of the marketing team to be able to create a blog post
- Anyone to be able to read a blog post
- The original author or a manager to be able to edit a blog post
- The original author or a manager to be able to delete a blog post
- Anyone to be able to list all blog posts

From those requirements you decide to implement RBAC (Role Based Access
Controls). You define your roles as:

- Manager
- Marketer
- Guest

You also create a "Posts Controller" which has five actions:

- Create
- Read
- Update
- Delete
- List

Lastly you set up an authentication system. The authentication system will
always return one of the roles you implemented. If the user is logged in then
you will get back either a "Manager" or a "Marketer" (depending on their job 
within your company). If the user is not logged in you will get back a "Guest".

Development goes well until you start to implement authorisation for the
"Update" action.

## Question

Where should the authorisation happen for the "Update" action in this web
application?

Be sure not to confuse authentication (checking if the user is logged in and
determining who they are) with authorisation (checking if the user allowed to
do what they want to).

## Possible Answers

1. The model.

   - It cannot go in the action because you cannot check the original author
     of the blog post until you have called the model.
   - Your business logic should go in the model to stick to the "thin
     controller, fat model" rule of thumb.
   - The authorisation should not happen in the action because we will end up
     duplicating our logic across multiple actions that call the same model
     methods.
2. The action.

   - The authorisation cannot happen in the model because not all actions use a
     model. What about the "Create" action? It may only render an HTML form. 
     This means the authorisation is skipped.
   - Passing a user object to every model method seems cumbersome. Not so for
     the action because it's aware of the HTTP session where the user is
     stored.
   - What happens when a scheduled task or cronjob runs? RBAC has no place here
     unless we implement a "System" role. If the authorisation happens in the
     action scheduled tasks don't need to be aware of roles.
   - What if it's too late to check the authorisation by the time the model
     method is called? The method being called may be one of three called in
     an action. If the first two pass and the third fails you may introduce
     bugs to your web application. Doing all your authorisation checks upfront
     avoids this.
3. The action and the model.

   - Splitting up the authorisation into "Role based authentication" and
     "Business logic authentication" might work. But where would you draw the 
     line?
4. Somewhere else.

   - Am I missing a layer in my MVC web application? Would service layers or
     middleware help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and researching I think I found the answer to my own question.

To satisfy the requirements I needed to implement "Attribute Based Access Control" (abbreviated to [ABAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-Based_Access_Control)). It is also called "Claims Based Access Control" and "Policy Based Access Control".

ABAC uses four inputs to reach a decision on whether the current user is allowed to do what they're trying to do. The four inputs are:

- Subject - This is the user object. It would contain the user ID and their role(s).
- Action - This would be the controller name and the action name.
- Resource - This would be the blog post object in the example I gave.
- Environment - This would probably be fixed in the example I gave. But you could use this to differentiate between a web application, an API or a scheduled task.

The check should happen inside the action. Here's a quick PHP pseudo code example:

```
class PostsController {
    public function updateAction() {
        // get the post
        $model = new PostsModel();
        $post = $model->findById($_GET['id']);
        // check authorisation
        $authorised = $this->authorisor->check(
            $this->user,
            "PostsController::updateAction",
            $post,
            APP
        );
        // build response etc.
    }
}
```

It should be obvious why it needs to happen inside the action; there is no resource (the post in the example above) to check against otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, when you think to the authorization management you must often think about an **Aspect** understood as an element of **AOP** paradigm (or something similar). So it's something that stays on top of all your application layers but with a non-intrusive approach.

Talking about **where** the authorization management should be placed i think that it must be placed in a common place where your "action endpoints" will be called and managed. For example if you have a rest or soap api, all the authorization management could be placed into one of the first request handlers, in order to reject unauthorized user before every controller action is called.

Back to a simple MVC application with 3 layer you could define an `AuthManager` that is called before each controller action. 
A different and more intrusive approach should be used if your authorization mamagement involves also some view dynamic modifications but this is a different question.